# CS1003: Syntax error, '>' expected in Razor

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-4, razor

I'm trying something new (to me) in using an abstract base class for my layout viewmodel.

The problem is that when I run the site as is, it throws a very cryptic (to me) exception. What does this exception mean, and what might I do to resolve it?

**Layout**

```
@model MyApp.Core.ViewModels.LayoutViewModel

<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width" />
    <title>@Model.Title</title>
</head>
<body>
    <div>
       @RenderBody()
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

**Index**

```
@model MyApp.Core.ViewModels.Home.IndexViewModel;

@{
    Layout = "~/Views/Shared/_Layout.cshtml";
}


<h1>@Model.Body</h1>
```

**LayoutViewModel**

```
namespace MyApp.Core.ViewModels
{
    public abstract class LayoutViewModel
    {
        public string Title { get; set; }
    }
}
```

**IndexViewModel**

```
namespace MyApp.Core.ViewModels.Home
{
    public class IndexViewModel : LayoutViewModel
    {
        public string Body { get; set; }
    }
}
```

**Controller**

```
[HttpGet]
public ActionResult Index()
{
    var model = new IndexViewModel
        {
            Title = "Hello World",
            Body = "Hello World"
        };


    return View(model);
}
```

And the Exception

> Compilation Error    Description: An error occurred during the
>   compilation of a resource required to service this request. Please
>   review the following specific error details and modify your source
>   code appropriately.
>
> Compiler Error Message: CS1003: Syntax error, '>' expected
>
> Source Error:
>
> ```
> Line 27:
> Line 28:
> Line 29:     public class _Page_Views_Home_Index_cshtml : 
> System.Web.Mvc.WebViewPage<FutureStateMobile.Core.ViewModels.Home.IndexViewModel;>
> { 
> Line 30:          
> Line 31: #line hidden
> ```
>
> Source File: c:\Users\Chase\AppData\Local\Temp\Temporary ASP.NET
>   Files\root\b314e0d7\36f522db\App_Web_index.cshtml.a8d08dba.yr7oemfz.0.cs
>   Line: 29

Answer (score 44, accepted):

Compare and contrast:

**Layout**

```
@model MyApp.Core.ViewModels.LayoutViewModel
```

**Index**

```
@model MyApp.Core.ViewModels.Home.IndexViewModel;
```

Got it yet? Here's the answer:

> one of them has a `;` which shouldn't be there

Comment: ah, hahaha, good catch. I spend too much time in the .cs that the `;` is second nature.

Comment: >! nice way to play hide and seek :) doesn't work on the comment box though.

Comment: @chase learning what razor treats as markup and what it treats as code seems to turn up a new surprise weekly for me :)

Comment: @AakashM How on earth did you come up with that? I mean, the error message is in no way indocative what is wrong. Neither does it point to the problem causing line in cshtml. Definitely an upvote.

Comment: oh geez. If it was a snake it would have bit me. thanks

Answer (score 1):

I just add the line twice, and deleted... problem solved!

```
@model MyApp.Core.ViewModels.LayoutViewModel
@model MyApp.Core.ViewModels.Layout_OrOther_Model
```

Try to compile, you get an error (only one model blah, blah..)
Delete one of them.

```
@model MyApp.Core.ViewModels.LayoutViewModel
```

Compile.

That works for me!

Answer (score -1):

bad:

```
<%@ Control Language="C#" Inherits="System.Web.Mvc.ViewUserControl<IEnumerable<DSNY.Core.Interfaces.IUser>" %>
```

versus

good:

```
<%@ Control Language="C#" Inherits="System.Web.Mvc.ViewUserControl<IEnumerable<DSNY.Core.Interfaces.IUser>>" %>
```

Compiler kept telling me it was expecting an extra `>`.

Comment: ugh -- doesn't show the line at the top of my .ASCX that had only one GT in stead of two GTs.