# How can I find/fix a compile error in auto-generated code?

Tags: asp.net, razor

This fails in production and on the test system, but works fine on the dev system. Feels like something got lost in deployment, but it is not complaining about a missing file or resource.

The code below is giving me "Compiler Error Message: CS1003: Syntax error, '>' expected on line 29" on this line:

```
   public class    _Page_Areas_SecurityGuard_Views_Dashboard_Index_cshtml : System.Web.Mvc.WebViewPage < SecurityGuard.ViewModels.DashboardViewModel() > {
```

But there are no mismatched brackets in this file or the source file that I can find.
Everything in Execute looks to be regurgitated correctly from the source file given.

```
    #pragma checksum "C:\{path}\Areas\SecurityGuard\Views\Dashboard\Index.cshtml" "{ff1816ec-aa5e-4d10-87f7-6f4963833460}" "CB3D0E13D4917D76BCD475640DD7740F6F1AB1D5"
   //------------------------------------------------------------------------------
   // <auto-generated>
   //     This code was generated by a tool.
   //     Runtime Version:4.0.30319.42000
   //
   //     Changes to this file may cause incorrect behavior and will be lost if
   //     the code is regenerated.
   // </auto-generated>
   //------------------------------------------------------------------------------

   namespace ASP {
       using System;
       ....

       public class    _Page_Areas_SecurityGuard_Views_Dashboard_Index_cshtml : System.Web.Mvc.WebViewPage<SecurityGuard.ViewModels.DashboardViewModel()> {

   #line hidden

           public _Page_Areas_SecurityGuard_Views_Dashboard_Index_cshtml() {
           }

           protected ASP.global_asax ApplicationInstance {
               get {
                   return ((ASP.global_asax)(Context.ApplicationInstance));
               }
           }

           public override void Execute() {

               #line 2 "C:\{path}\Areas\SecurityGuard\Views\Dashboard\Index.cshtml"

       ViewBag.Title = "Index";
       Layout = "~/Areas/SecurityGuard/Views/Shared/_SecurityGuardLayoutPage.cshtml";

   ....
}
```

The source file

```
@model SecurityGuard.ViewModels.DashboardViewModel
@{
    ViewBag.Title = "Index";
    Layout = "~/Areas/SecurityGuard/Views/Shared/_SecurityGuardLayoutPage.cshtml";
}
<h2>
    Manage Users and Roles</h2>
<div class="fl w48pc mr20">
    <fieldset>
        <legend>Manage Users</legend>
        <p>@Html.ActionLink("Manage Users", "Index", "Membership", new { area = "SecurityGuard" }, null)
            | @Html.ActionLink("Create User", "CreateUser", "Membership", new { area = "SecurityGuard" }, null)</p>
        <table>
            <tr>
                <td>
                    Total Users:
                </td>
                <td>@Model.TotalUserCount
                </td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>
                    Users Online:
                </td>
                <td>@Model.TotalUsersOnlineCount
                </td>
            </tr>
        </table>
    </fieldset>
</div>
<div class="fr w48pc">
    <fieldset>
        <legend>Manage Roles</legend>
        <p>@Html.ActionLink("Manage Roles", "Index", "Role", new { area = "SecurityGuard" }, null)</p>
        <table>
            <tr>
                <td>
                    Total Roles:
                </td>
                <td>@Model.TotalRolesCount
                </td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>
                </td>
                <td>
                </td>
            </tr>
        </table>
    </fieldset>
</div>
```

The referenced model

```
using System;
....

namespace SecurityGuard.ViewModels
{
    public class DashboardViewModel
    {
        public string TotalUserCount { get; set; }
        public string TotalUsersOnlineCount { get; set; }
        public string TotalRolesCount { get; set; }
    }
}
```

Comment: What does your `@model` declaration look like in that view?

Comment: @CodeCaster Added.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That line of code has `< SecurityGuard.ViewModels.DashboardViewModel() >` but I don't think those parentheses belong there. Try changing it to `<SecurityGuard.ViewModels.DashboardViewModel>` and see if it compiles.

Comment: I see what you are saying. It isn't that the > isn't there, but that it sees the ( first when it expects a >.

Comment: I can edit it, but as advertised, it gets overwritten by a new copy with the same error. Not sure how to change this.

Comment: Ah ok. Where is this auto-generated code coming from?

Comment: procmon shows that w3wp.exe reads the C:\{path}\Areas\SecurityGuard\Views\Dashboard\Index.cshtml file, then immediately after writes this file. So I assume that w3wp creates that file.

Comment: Looking closer at the compiler error message confirms your thought that it is complaining about finding the ( instead of the >

Comment: Oh I see now. Check your `@model` directive at the top of your .cshtml page in prod/test and make sure you didn't add those parentheses at the end (like `@model SecurityGuard.ViewModels.DashboardViewModel()`)

Comment: Is it possible that you are targeting a different .NET Framework in your publish settings? Or it really seems that at some point, the () was accidentally added at the end of the @model directive...but I can't understand how that would have gotten past the compile & build. This SO question has a very similar compile error as yours: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18877058/cs1003-syntax-error-expected-in-razor

Comment: Searching the project didn't find a match, but searching the folder found it cached in the Publish directory. Thanks.

Comment: Awesome, glad you were able to track it down